# How to display alternate text on iPhone/Android where flash is not supported

Tags: html

I am trying to display alternate text on browsers/devices where flash is not supported.
I have searched different sites and tried different codes but I'm failing to get anything effective.

Code is below, the flash displays animated text:

```
class="result10435918"
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,40,0"
width="595"
height="39"
id="haxe"
align="middle">
<param name="movie" value="logo70644855.swf"/>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />

<embed src="images/homeheader2.swf"
       wmode="transparent"
       width="595"
       height="39"
       name="haxe"
       quality="high"
       allowScriptAccess="always"
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
       pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"

></embed>
```

Thanks
Ciaran

Answer (score 0):

Try using an object tag to wrap the flash piece, and inside of it have your fallback text.  Setting a width and height in the object tag defines a specific amount of space for the flash to take up.  If that flash isn't loaded, it will display what else is inside of the object tag (the fallback text).  You can also include images or something else in place of the Fallback Text.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="yourmovie.swf" width="400" height="300">
    <param name="movie" value="yourmovie.swf" />
    Fallback Text Here
</object>
```

Comment: Thanks,so the DIV tag with altetnate text should enclose the embed tags of the code ?

Comment: Hi Again,have tried and cant get this to work. I have tried inserting the DIV tag before the opening OBJECT tag and also just prior to the embed tag. <div id="images/homeheader2.swf">Alternate Text Here</div>
I think I may be doing something fundamentally wrong with the placement and content of the DIV tag.

Also tried replacing the id="images/homeheader2.swf" with id="logo70644855.swf" but still displays both alternate text and cash animated text. any suggestions as ave tried nearlyy everything!!!

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately just appears above the animated flash text. Tried wrapping the flash piece with a DIV tag and alternate text and that just appeared above the animated logo or below depending on where the alt text was. Just to clarify the embed tag is used in the event the browser does not read the object tag? Im not sure if this has something to do with it.

Comment: Also tried adding alt text in a <p></p> tag inside the embed tags but doest seem to work either as the rest of the code within the <embed> tag is read as text, it I take out the <p> tag the text appears in red and is not recognised in non-flash supporting browsers anyway, can't think of anything else at this point!!!